# Error in overrideing the cleanup method in the mapper using old Hadoop API

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a map task in which I override the `cleanup` function as shown below, however the IDE shows an error message saying "The method cleanup(Mapper.Context) of type GraphAnonymization.Map_Phase3 must override or implement a supertype method"

```
public static class Map_Phase3 extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> { 
 @Override
 public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
     context.write()        
     ...
 }
}
```

The method `cleanup` is not defined in the old Hadoop API. Do I have to switch to new API?

Comment: Are you importing the correct Mapper? What version are you using/targeting?

Comment: I'm using hadoop-core.1.1.1.jar file. I've written lots of map-reduce programs using this api and they all work properly. Downloaded from http://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-1.1.1/

Comment: Is your source level at 1.6+?

Comment: @DaveNewton: what does it mean that 1.6+?

Comment: Java 1.6 allows the override annotation on interface method methods, 1.5 doesn't.

Comment: I'm using java 1.7, I've used override for other method and there is no problem there.

Comment: Which `Mapper` are you importing? I don't recall a `cleanup` in the older version. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Mapper.html, http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/MapReduceBase.html

Answer (score 1):

In the old API (mapred) the Mapper interface extends the Closable interface - which defines the close method (rather than cleanup which is the method for the new mapreduce API mapper).

So amend your code to the following:

```
public static class Map_Phase3 extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> { 
    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

The old API doesn't pass you the OutputCollector for you to write out any final or accumulated values so you'll need to cache the value passed to the map method in an instance variable for your mapper. Finally you'll need to wrap any exceptions in a RuntimeException as the close method doesn't define any exceptions being thrown